# Problems with a list and array

Tags: c#, arrays, return, method-call

I have been working on a program that can calculate molecularweight from a chemical formula. 
So far it works pretty well, until this error occured. I want to make an array that split the chemical formula (It works fine). From here I want to make a method call, that send the array to another method. Where it is used to calculate the molecularweight from the elements in the chemical formula, and add it to a new list. Then return the list to the first method. Here's is the code (Only showing for 1 element or code gets too large);

```
private void Textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = Textbox1.Text;
    string pattern = @"([A-Z][a-z]?\d*|[A-Z]?\d*)";
    string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

    MoleculeweightCalculator(substrings);

    Textbox2.Text = Convert.ToString(MoleculeWeightList.Sum());
}

private static MoleculeweightCalculator(string[] substrings)
{
    List<double> MoleculeWeightList = new List<double>();

    foreach (string match in substrings)
    {
        if (match == "H")
        {
            MoleculeWeightList.Add(1.008);
        }
    }
return MoleculeWeightList;
}
```

The problem is that it won't allow me to send the array to the other method and returning the list to the first method again. Any ideas what is wrong? Or how to solve it?

Comment: `return` is lowercase, and `MoleculeweightCalculator` needs a return type in the method signature, in this case: `List<double>`

Comment: plus you may want to move the return statement outside of the foreach loop.

Comment: Oh yeah return is outside of foreach. just wrote it wrong in here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your code, `return` has to be lowercase and you should place it out of the loop, then the return type is missing. Moreover you aren't storing the returned data.

This should at least compile:

```
private void Textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string input = Textbox1.Text;
    string pattern = @"([A-Z][a-z]?\d*|[A-Z]?\d*)";
    string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

    var result = MoleculeweightCalculator(substrings);

    Textbox2.Text = Convert.ToString(result.Sum());
}

private static List<double> MoleculeweightCalculator(string[] substrings){
    List<double> MoleculeWeightList = new List<double>();

    foreach (string match in substrings){
        if (match == "H")
            MoleculeWeightList.Add(1.008);
    }

    return MoleculeWeightList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually using the return value. The `MoleculeWeightList` variable is local *to that function*, and more specifically, to that **scope** and can't be used outside of it. But because you `return` it, you can do this:

```
List<double> weightList = MoleculeweightCalculator(substrings);

Textbox2.Text = Convert.ToString(weightList.Sum());
```

That assigns the return value to a local variable in the *calling* method, which you can then use later in the method.